# How to resolve Java Certificate Issue?

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I am able to access a WSDL via Browser but when I try to access the same WSDL file via java application deployed in my local machine I encounter the below certificate error. I am using java 1.8

I've gone through many answers here for the same issue and I tried almost all of them but still the issue persists.

**What I've done so far**

1- I exported the certificate from the Chrome, saved it as Base 64.

2- Paste the cer in my JDK location which is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\security\mig_root.cer

3- I ran this command: keytool -import -alias cac -file "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\security\mig_root.cer" -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit

4- Restart my machine.

5- Still issue persists.

**Error**

`javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: https://myURL?WSDL. It failed with:  sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.`

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy the certificate into the directory
   Java_home\Jre\Lib\Security
2. Change your directory to
   Java_home\Jre\Lib\Security>
3. Import the certificate to a trust store.

keytool -import -alias ca -file somecert.cer -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit [Return]

Trust this certificate: Yes

Comment: I don't see any difference between you and my method. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Might be JRE does not have the root CA as a trusted entry in keystore

Comment: OP is using the default install on Windows, which is under `\Program Files`, and modern Windows (since 8 or maybe 7) doesn't like anything but a signed installer writing under `\Program Files*` because most viruses and malware (try to) do so. Anything you try to write there may fail or just be ignored. Either install elsewhere, or copy the truststore somewhere else to modify and use.

Comment: Are you saying to change the location of JDK?